# Lock screen event in Blackberry 10 app

Tags: events, blackberry-10, lockscreen

I wanted to know if there is a way to get a event/notification in your application when the device's screen is locked by the user.

Currently, When the user is in login screen and submits the login detail and locks the screen. the login process (Request is sent to the server and response is received for that) is getting completed. I wanted to cancel the request at that particular instance.

Is there a way to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a signal you can connect to the slot and get the update when lock state changes. Take a look at [`DeviceLockState`](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__platform__devicelockstate.html). This is an example:

```
mHomeScreen = new bb::platform::HomeScreen(this);
bool res = connect(mHomeScreen, SIGNAL(lockStateChanged(bb::platform::DeviceLockState::Type)),
        this, SLOT(onLockStateChanged(bb::platform::DeviceLockState::Type)));
```

And your slot:

```
void YourApp::onLockStateChanged(bb::platform::DeviceLockState::Type state) {
    if (state == bb::platform::DeviceLockState::ScreenLocked) {
        qDebug() << "Device locked";
    }
}
```

You may also find `DeviceLockState::PasswordLocked` state interesting .